# How to append list inside list in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I have created an empty lists using

```
var lift = mutableListOf<Any(mutableListOf<Any(),mutableListOf<Any>())
```

But

`lift[0].add(1)`

Gives me error.
How to add elements to list inside list

Comment: What error does it give you?

Comment: `error: unresolved reference: add
    lift[0].add(1)`

Comment: Do you want to add to the main list? or to a list inside the main list?

Comment: I want to add elements to list inside the main list

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that you have upcast the list type to `Any` instead of `MutableList<Any>`.

If you just typed:

```
mutableListOf(mutableListOf<Any>(),mutableListOf<Any>())
```

the type of items in the list is implicitly `MutableList<Any>`. But since you added `<Any>` like this:

```
mutableListOf<Any>(mutableListOf<Any>(),mutableListOf<Any>())
```

the compiler treats retrieved items as type `Any` instead of the specific type `MutableList<Any>` so you can't call functions on them.

You could also explicitly state the type like this, but it is not necessary:

```
mutableListOf<MutableList<Any>>(mutableListOf<Any>(),mutableListOf<Any>())
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
val lift: MutableList<MutableList<Any>> = mutableListOf<MutableList<Any>>(mutableListOf<Any>(),mutableListOf<Any>())
```

Comment: Why up-cast and then down-cast back to the original type?